# Rotating and changing the size of image in Android Camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm new to android development and recently, I've made a simple camera app with android but I have to problems that I cannot solve. First, I've rotated the preview screen to 90 degree so that the surfaceview would be in a portrait mode. I 've used the code below .

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    if(mCamera != null) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
```

But the problem isn't solved. After I take the shot and check the image in the folder the jpg image that I took with my app is saved horizontally with a bad resolution.

I'm not sure how to explain it clearly but what I want to do is to alter the image size and save it in a portrait mode. 
The code to save the image is like the sample below, but I'm not certain how and where I can change the size and rotation before saving. Sorry for my bad English. It would be great if I can have some clear tips for noobs.

```
private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {

    @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;

                // Write to SD Card
                try {
                    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
                    dir.mkdirs();               

                    String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    outStream.write(data[0]);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
```

Is it possible to rotate the data in PictureCallback?

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            //change the rotarion 

            new SaveImageTask().execute(data);
            resetCam();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Your English is fine, don't worry.

Comment: possible duplicate of *[Issues taking picture with Android (Vertical Camera | Portrait)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294868/issues-taking-picture-with-android-vertical-camera-portrait)* and many others. Note that some devices do save the image in portrait orientation, but most only set an EXIF flag (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023696/setrotation90-to-take-picture-in-portrait-mode-does-not-work-on-samsung-device).